# Is there a silent remote notification that does not launch the app into background?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

A silent remote notification must include the key `content-available: 1` which also launches a suspended app into background.

Is there a way to send a silent push notification that does not contain any user-visible information but also does not launch the app into background?

It does not work by simply removing the key `content-available: 1`, because a remote notification without the keys `badge`, `alert` or `sound` does not seem to be delivered to the client.

Comment: And what would be its purpose? If the user can’t see it, and the system shouldn’t do anything with it, then why should it be delivered?

Comment: @Losiowaty You are missing the use case that the notification can contain custom keys that are handled while the app is running.

Comment: So send a silent push and check if the app is running and act accordingly - if it is in the background you can either totally discard the payload or persist it to disk for processing when user opens the app. On the other hand, there are different ways for the backend to sens information to app, without active polling - web sockets fot example. Remember that notification delivery is not guaranteed (though it is rare for it to fail).

Comment: @Losiowaty I think you are missing my question. How can you “send a silent push and check if the app is running” when a silent push always launches the app?

Comment: You can check if the app is in the background state - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationstate

Comment: Again, you are missing the point. I want to know how I can send a silent push that does not launch the app if it is in suspended state.

Comment: You can’t. You could call your backend with information that your app is active/suspended and have it not send notifications when it is not active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently that's not possible.

A remote notification to be delivered has to contain:

- at least one of the keys `alert`, `sound`, `badge` which makes it a user-visible notification or
- the key `content-available: 1` which makes it a silent notification and launches the app in background